GraphQL and React: cursor pagination and fetchMore
So, I just wanted to make sure I was doing this correctly because it doesn't feel right.
What I want:

When I click the button to fetchMore, it automatically updates my page to show the new results.

What I have:
getPosts.ts
import { gql } from '@apollo/client'

export const GET_POSTS = gql`
  query GetPosts(
    $after: String
    $filterBy: [PostListFilterByInput!]
    $limit: Int!
    $offset: Int
    $orderByString: String
    $reverse: Boolean
    $spaceIds: [ID!]
  ) {
    posts(
      after: $after
      filterBy: $filterBy
      limit: $limit
      offset: $offset
      orderByString: $orderByString
      reverse: $reverse
      spaceIds: $spaceIds
    ) {
      totalCount
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          description
          reactionsCount
          fields {
            key
            value
            relationEntities {
              medias {
                ... on Image {
                  urls {
                    medium
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

usePosts.ts hook
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client'
import {
  GetPostsQuery,
  GetPostsQueryVariables,
  Image
} from '@/graphql/generated/types'
import { GRAPHQL_VARIABLES } from '@/constants/graphql'
import { GET_POSTS } from '@/graphql/queries/posts/getPosts'

export interface IPost {
  id: string
  title: string
  description: string
  reactionsCount: number
  urls: {
    medium?: string
  }
}

export const useGetPosts = () => {
  const { data, loading, error, fetchMore } = useQuery<
    GetPostsQuery,
    GetPostsQueryVariables
  >(GET_POSTS, {
    variables: {
      ...GRAPHQL_VARIABLES,
      after: ''
    }
  })

  const posts: IPost[] =
    data?.posts?.edges?.map(({ node }) => {
      let urls = {}
      if (node.fields) {
        for (const field of node.fields) {
          if (field.key === 'cover_image' && field.relationEntities?.medias) {
            const image = field.relationEntities.medias.find(
              (media) => media.__typename === 'Image'
            ) as Image
            if (image) {
              urls = image.urls || {}
            }
          }
        }
      }

      return {
        id: node.id || '',
        title: node.title || '',
        description: node.description || '',
        reactionsCount: node.reactionsCount,
        urls
      }
    }) || []

  const hasNextPage = data?.posts?.pageInfo?.hasNextPage

  const endCursor = data?.posts?.pageInfo?.endCursor

  return { posts, loading, error, fetchMore, hasNextPage, endCursor }
}

Gallery.tsx component
import GalleryItem from '@/components/feature/GalleryItem'
import { Button } from '@/components/base/Button'

import { useGetPosts } from './hooks/usePosts'

const Gallery: React.FC = () => {
  const { posts, fetchMore, hasNextPage, endCursor } = useGetPosts()

  const loadMore = () => {
    fetchMore({
      variables: {
        after: endCursor
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex justify-center">
        <div className="m-8 grid max-w-[1100px] grid-cols-1 gap-8 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3">
          {posts.map((post) => (
            <GalleryItem key={post?.id} post={post} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-10 flex justify-center">
        {hasNextPage && (
          <Button
            className="rounded bg-blue-500 px-4 py-2 font-bold text-white hover:bg-blue-700"
            onClick={loadMore}
          >
            Show More
          </Button>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Gallery

cache.ts graphql cache config:
import { InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client'

export const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        posts: {
          keyArgs: false,
          merge(existing = { edges: [], pageInfo: {} }, incoming) {
            const mergedEdges = [...existing.edges, ...incoming.edges]
            return {
              ...incoming,
              edges: mergedEdges
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

Is this correct or is there a better way to merge data after doing a fetchMore request?

Okay, so here's how I got fetchMore working correctly:
Correctly mapping the array of post objects (this fixed my fetchMore issues):
./src/graphql/cache.ts
import { InMemoryCache, Reference, StoreObject } from '@apollo/client'

interface PostNode extends StoreObject {
  __ref: string
}

interface PostEdge {
  __typename: string
  node: PostNode | Reference
}

export const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        posts: {
          keyArgs: false,
          merge(existing = { edges: [], pageInfo: {} }, incoming) {
            const existingEdges = existing.edges || []
            const incomingEdges = incoming.edges || []

            const edgeMap = new Map<string, PostEdge>()

            existingEdges.forEach((edge: PostEdge) => {
              edgeMap.set(edge.node.__ref, edge)
            })

            incomingEdges.forEach((edge: PostEdge) => {
              edgeMap.set(edge.node.__ref, edge)
            })

            const mergedEdges = Array.from(edgeMap.values())

            return {
              ...incoming,
              edges: mergedEdges
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

Now, when I want to change a post reaction, I can use a post fragment:
./src/components/feature/ReactionButton/hooks/useAddReaction.ts
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client'
import { ADD_REACTION } from '@/graphql/mutations/reactions/addReaction'
import {
  AddReactionMutation,
  AddReactionMutationVariables
} from '@/graphql/generated/types'

export const POST_FRAGMENT = gql`
  fragment PostFragment on Post {
    id
    reactionsCount
  }
`

const useAddReaction = () => {
  const [mutation] = useMutation<
    AddReactionMutation,
    AddReactionMutationVariables
  >(ADD_REACTION)

  const addReaction = (postId: string, reaction: string) => {
    mutation({
      variables: { input: { reaction }, postId },
      update: (cache, { data }) => {
        if (!data) return

        const postIdCache = `Post:${postId}`
        const existingPost = cache.readFragment<{
          id: string
          reactionsCount: number
        }>({
          id: postIdCache,
          fragment: POST_FRAGMENT
        })

        if (!existingPost) return

        const updatedReactionsCount = existingPost.reactionsCount + 1

        cache.writeFragment({
          id: postIdCache,
          fragment: POST_FRAGMENT,
          data: {
            id: postId,
            reactionsCount: updatedReactionsCount
          }
        })
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        if (
          error.graphQLErrors.some(
            (e) => e.message === 'You already reacted to this post.'
          )
        ) {
          // TODO: Notify the user
          console.error('You have already reacted to this post.')
        }
      }
    })
  }

  return { addReaction }
}

export default useAddReaction

